# Inverse of $f(x) = x^{3}-x^{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function, cubics

Can anybody find the inverse of $f:(-1,0) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x^{3} - x^{2}$ ?

Comment: [The answer is not pretty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3-x%5E2%3Da). You can derive it using the [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano's_method)

Comment: The answer is actually: *You can do it!*. And yes, you should use Cardano's method, as mentioned by @Wojovu.

Comment: It also has nothing to do with functional analysis so please use proper tagging.

Comment: Thank you!, I will read Cardano's Theorem! And sorry for the incorrect tagging

Comment: Is this question resolved enough to be deleted?